# A function satisfying Cauchy-Riemann but not continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by

$$
f(z)=\frac{z^4}{|z|^3} \,\, {\rm if} \,\, z \neq 0 \\
    0 \,\, {\rm if} \,\, z=0
$$

By some calculations, it can be shown that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations in z=0. But is it differentiable in z=0?

Comment: Look at the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It is not differentiable in $z=0$, because with definition the limit
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h^3}{|h|^3}=\left(\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h}{|h|}\right)^3$$
doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

No, if you take $h=(1+i)k$, with $k>0$, and let $k\rightarrow 0^{+}$, the difference quotient $|f(h)/h|=2/(|1-i||1+i|)$ does not converge to zero.